# MSVC's _M_X64 Predefined Macro Clarification

Tags: c++, c, macros, visual-c++

The documentation for [MSVC's Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28VS.80%29.aspx#_predir_table_1..3) state "`_M_X64` [is] Defined for x64 processors." What does that mean, exactly? Will it be defined:

- When I'm building *for* x64 processors, or
- When I'm building *with* x64 processors?

Specifically, I'm looking for a compiler switch for the former case, not the latter. Will `_M_X64` suffice for that purpose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that _M_X64 is the target processor.  It is what you are building for, not what you are building on.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you can type the code like this.

```
#ifdef _M_X64
#pragma comment(lib, "TEST64BIT.LIB")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "TEST32BIT.LIB")
#endif
```